# Dwm status bar and web forms display weird fonts

Tags: arch-linux, dwm

I'm using Arch Linux with dwm desktop. I was trying to make some changes in my ~/.xinitrc, and now my dwm status bar displays weird characters. I reverted all the changes i made in `/etc/X11/xconfig.d` and `~/.xinitrc,` but the problem persists. The characters get also displayed on some web forms too (which makes it very difficult for me to post even this). Do you have any idea what may cause this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it appears i was missing a monospace font, and default was falling back to wingdings or something. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is symptomatic of you not having installed a monospace font, and not having changed the font declaration in `.config.h`, the [default which ships with dwm](http://git.suckless.org/dwm/tree/config.def.h#n8) being:

```
static const char *fonts[]          = { "monospace:size=10" };
```